# Post to Twitter from my website with PHP

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I was looking at the Twitter API but I could not manage how can I automatically post to my twitter.

I want to visit a page on my website, which then posts the timestamp on my Twitter for example.

This code worked once, but after that, no more tweets are generated:

```
<?php
$consumerKey    = 'myKey';
$consumerSecret = 'myConsumerKey';
$oAuthToken     = 'theToken';
$oAuthSecret    = 'theSecret';

require_once('twitteroauth.php');

// create a new instance
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

//send a tweet
$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'My awesome timestamp msg'));

?>
```

Is there any reason that it worked once?

Comment: post your code and any error messages you get when it runs ... posting a link to a site with some random code that isnt "working anymore" helps no one

Comment: I have managed to make a simple script using oAuth. I am going to post it here when I get back home

Comment: Actually it worked once... then It seems like its posting, I mean, the script runs flawless, but doesnt post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're attempting to post the same message again, Twitter detects when your tweet is identical to the previous one and rejects it.

Comment: oh nice, let me try a different one

Answer (score 0):

The new Twitter api, makes this somewhat easy. Twitter provides a [page of Twitter buttons](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet) specifically designed to place on your webpage.

Comment: This is not the idea. The idea was to ping some html page on mywebsite, and this hit generates a post on twitter.